# obtener respuesta en objeto y no en array

Tags: php, laravel

hola amigos tengo esta funcion que retorna la respuesta en array y lo que deseo es obtener la respues en objeto

```
public function devOrg(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
                'c_empr'=>'required',
    ]);

    $devOrg = DB::select("SET NOCOUNT ON;exec liteDevOrg :c_empr"
            ,[
                "c_empr"=>$request->c_empr,
            ]);
   return $devOrg;
}
```

la respuesta que obtengo es la siguiente

```
[0:{"c_empr":"001",
"l_empr":"RESTAURANT GIRASOLES",
"l_repr":"OLIVERA SANDOVAL JOSE",
"l_dire":"CALLE REAL 1820 AZAPAMPA, CHILCA HUANCAYO  217147",
"n_ruc":"21345678321",
"n_tele":"064233872",
"l_ciud":"HUANCAYO",
"c_ubig":"120133",
"l_nomc":"RESTAURANT CAMPESTRE LOS GIRASOLES",
"l_logo":"szlBLM5QA3AMgBACAEAIAQAgBACAEAIAQAgBACAEAIAQAgBACAEAIAQAgBACAEAIAQAg"}]
```

y deseo obtener el siguiente resultado

```
{"c_empr":"001",
"l_empr":"RESTAURANT GIRASOLES",
"l_repr":"OLIVERA SANDOVAL JOSE",
"l_dire":"CALLE REAL 1820 AZAPAMPA, CHILCA HUANCAYO  217147",
"n_ruc":"21345678321",
"n_tele":"064233872",
"l_ciud":"HUANCAYO",
"c_ubig":"120133",
"l_nomc":"RESTAURANT CAMPESTRE LOS GIRASOLES",
"l_logo":"szlBLM5QA3AMgBACAEAIAQAgBACAEAIAQAgBACAEAIAQAgBACAEAIAQAgBACAEAIAQAg"}
```

de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Hola lo que podria es hacer agregar el metodo first(), de esta manera.

```
public function devOrg(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
                'c_empr'=>'required',
    ]);

    $devOrg = DB::select("SET NOCOUNT ON;exec liteDevOrg :c_empr"
            ,[
                "c_empr"=>$request->c_empr,
            ]);
$devOrg= collect($devOrg)->first();
   return $devOrg;
}
```

Comment: si trate de hacer eso, pero bota el siguiente error(Call to a member function first() on array)

Comment: Me parece que `first` solo trabaja con collections, dadas por el uso de los modelos, cosa que el OP no tiene en su consulta: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz tienes razón, es mejor primero convertir el array en collecction, ya se puede utilizar el metodo collect que es aplicable a collections.

Comment: @FredyAlarconOrdoñez ya puedes ver el nuevo código editado

Answer (score 1):

Puedes acceder a los elementos de ese array de la siguiente forma:

```
$c_empr = $devOrg['c_empr'];
$l_repr = $devOrg['l_repr'];
etc...
```

De todas formas, si lo que quieres es convertir una consulta en un objeto, te recomiendo directamente acceder al elemento del array:

```js
return $devOrg[0];
```